How do PROP structure and Cartesian-closed structure interact?
Consider FinSet, the category (equivalent to) the collection of functions between finite sets. On one hand, FinSet is a PROP, a "symmetric monoidal category generated by a single object"; on the other hand, FinSet is Cartesian closed. How do these interact? Is the interaction generalizable, or is it specific to categories which can be viewed as having natural numbers for objects?
My motivation is in compiling CCC terms to machines which happen to be described by PROPs. If there's a connection between their structures, then I hope to be constrained by it.

This can be moved to (Theoretical) Computer Science SE, but I thought it's a slightly better fit here.

What kind of interaction are you looking for? For instance, for a finite set $X$ you know that $X\times -\colon\mathrm{FinSet}\to\mathrm{FinSet}$ commutes with all colimits and hence in particular it defines a strict monoidal functor with respect to the cocartesian symmetric monoidal structure on $\mathrm{FinSet}$ you use to give the latter a PROP-structure. There are all kinds of results like this that one could mention, so it's hard to choose without knowing what you are after.

I suppose I'm asking what happens in any Cartesian-closed PROP, but what I've worked out on my own is nebulous. I can't even tell if there are multiple such categories, let alone whether such a category has any emergent properties.
